# protractor dropdown in java

Tags: java, protractor, dropdown

I'm trying to select one of the dropdowns, I've tried everything. css, xpath, name etc  Please have a look"

```
 `<select id="releasingPI" class="dropdown releasingPI 
   validate[custom[requiredInSelectFunction]]"data-prompt-position="topLeft"> 
   <option value="Vælg">Vælg</option>
   <option value="1043">one</option>
   <option value="4879">two</option>
   <option value="6112">three</option>
</select>`
```

in the other dropdown Ive used 
element(by.cssContaining‌​Text('option', 'one')).click();
but it was 'option name' instead of 'option value'

Comment: so element(by.cssContaining‌​Text('option', 'one')).click(); aint working, building xpath also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css lcator doesn't work because there's a space in that option. So you have to update your locator:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'one ')).click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this is not it, ive just deleted the real data in the code and left accidentaly the space. Thanks you I'm gonna edit this.

Comment: you could try next one: `element(by.id('releasingPI').all(by.tagName('option').get(1).click()`

Comment: Thank You.
Ive used
element(by.css('[value="1048"]'))
It acured that the main problem was with sleep

Comment: hm, ok) Could you mark answer that other people see that ths question has correct answer. Thx